# Range Check for Double datatype variable

Tags: java, double

I am converting a string to double value using Double.parseDouble. I want to put a range check on double value to check if it lies in by default range of double data type. Please suggest how can i make a range check for double variable.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried what happens when you use that method on a value that would be out of range? What makes you think you need to check a function that returns a **double** value? How do you think that this function would return a double value that is not a double value?!

Comment: The parseDouble will throw an NumberFormatException if it cannot parse the value. If you would like to constrain the value further, I suggest writing your own methods that then tests for the range you allow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, the range of double is `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` through `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`, and no real number is outside that range. If you want to eliminate the overflow to infinity cases, test `Double.isFinite(val)` after the conversion.